# find sum of integral of vector field

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, vector-spaces, curves

For $k ∈ \mathbb{N}$ let $\gamma_k$ be the curve traced by a point travelling, at constant speed 1, along a circle of radius $k$ centered in $O ∈ \mathbb R^2$. The point starts at $(k, 0)$ and completes a single loop. For odd $k$ the orientation is counter-clockwise, for even $k$ it’s clockwise. Write down a parametrisation of $γ_k$ and discuss to what extent is it unique. With
$$g(x,y)=(\frac {-y} {x^2 +y^2},\frac {x} {x^2 +y^2})$$

find $$\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{γ_k} g$$
for every $n \in \mathbb N$ as well as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \int_{γ_k}^* g$$
where $$\int_{γ_k}^* g= \frac 1 {\text{length}(γ_k)} \int_{γ_k} g$$ note $\int^*$ is a special sign.

I am trying to find the parametrisation but am not sure where to start and why would it be unique? For the sum of integrals, do I integrate scalar (from $0$ to $k$) for the scalar of $g$ and add them up, is there a shortcut? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. Yes, and as Maxim pointed out, $\vec{g}$ is not a conservative vector field but this is only because the partial derivatives have a unique point of discontinuity at $(0,0)$. Therefore, the line integral must vanish whenever we take it over a simple closed curve that does not enclose $(0,0)$ ; the line integral is invariant when taken over those simple closed curves both enclosed by $\gamma_k$ and intersecting $\gamma_k$ at least twice. For odd $k$ we have  $$\int_{\gamma_k} \vec{g}(x,y)\;\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{k^2}\langle-\sin(t),\cos(t)\rangle\cdot k\langle-\sin(t),\cos(t)\rangle\;dt=\frac{2\pi}{k}$$ with $\;\;\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\gamma_k}^* \vec{g}(x,y)\;dr=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}(-1)^{k+1}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ as changing the curve orientation only changes the sign of the line integral yielding an alternating Basel sum.

Comment: thank you sir, and is it unique for the parameterisation part? im not sure how the direction would affect my parametrisation of (kcos(t),ksin(t))

Comment: Changing the orientation of $\gamma_k$ only changes the sign of the integral much like reversing the ornaments of the Riemann integral ; i.e., $$\int_a^b\;f(x)\;dx\;=-\int_b^a\;f(x)\;dx$$

Comment: We have $\partial_x g_y = \partial_y g_x$, not $\partial_x g_y = -\partial_y g_x$. But this is not a sufficient condition for a field to be conservative. $g$ is an example of a field which is not conservative on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$.

Comment: @Maxim. I've made corrections. I rushed some algebra and overlooked the discontinuity at $(0,0)$. However, the line integral of $g$ remains unchanged up to sign when taken over two curves which concatenate into a simple closed curve that does not enclose the origin. For example, $\gamma_k$ can be replaced with any inscribed square enclosed by $\gamma_k$ and the line integral remains unchanged up to sign depending on the orientation given.

Comment: Which shows that $\int_{\gamma_k} g \cdot dr$ can only differ by a sign. There cannot be a $1/k$ factor.

Comment: @Maxim. $\gamma_k:\;\vec r(t)=k\langle\cos t,\sin t\rangle$ where $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$ counterclockwise for odd $k$. On $\gamma_k$, $\vec g(x,y)=\frac{1}{k^2}\langle-\sin t,\cos t\rangle$ while $\vec r'(t)\;dt=k\langle-\sin (t),\cos (t)\rangle\;dt$. After taking the dot product only $\frac{1}{k}$ is left in the integrand.

Comment: @Maxim. To evaluate $\int_{\gamma_k}^*$ we simply divide the result $\frac{2\pi}{k}$ by the length $2\pi k$ of $\gamma_k$ which yields $\frac{1}{k^2}$ for odd $k$ and thus $-\frac{1}{k^2}$ for even $k$.